# Python 2.7 - inheritance - class methods - class attributes

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance, class-method, class-attributes

Suppose i have the following code:

```
class Parent(object):
    counter = 0

    @classmethod
    def inc(cls):
        cls.counter += 1

class Child(Parent):
    pass

Child.inc()
print Parent.counter, Child.counter
```

In my tests, this code outputs: 
    0 1

It seems that the above code will create an attribute counter on the child and increment it. I've tried using super as in:

```
class Child(Parent):
    @classmethod
    def inc(cls):
        super(Child,cls).inc()
```

But the results are the same.

How can i make the inc method increment the Parent, in a way that both Parent and Child stays with the same counter and print:
    1 1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to increment `Parent.counter`, refer to `Parent.counter`, not `cls.counter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class methods bind to the *current class*; that's by design; so calling `Parent.inc()` binds `cls` to `Parent`, and `Child.inc()` binds `cls` to `Child`. In the latter case then, the expression

```
cls.counter += 1
```

is basically the same thing as:

```
cls.counter = cls.counter + 1
```

which at the start *reads* `Parent.counter` (because `Child.counter` doesn't exist), but then *writes* to `Child.counter`.

If you only want `Parent.counter` to be updated, use an explicit reference to the class:

```
class Parent(object):
    counter = 0

    @classmethod
    def inc(cls):
        Parent.counter += 1
```

and ignore the `cls` attribute.